# How do you know when you'e found all the critical points? Is there a rule?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For example, for $f\left(x,y\right)=y^3+3x^2y-6x^2-6y^2+2$,

$f_x\left(a,b\right)=$   $6xy-12x$

and

$f_y\left(a,b\right)=$   $3y^2+3x^2-12y$

How many critical points am I looking for? How do I know when I've found them all?

Comment: There are only two critical points.

Comment: I assume you meant $f_x(x,y)$ and $f_y(x,y)$?

Answer (score 2):

$\tag 1 f_x\left(x,y\right)=6xy-12x = 0, f_y\left(x,y\right)= 3y^2+3x^2-12y = 0$

From the first equation we have:

$$6xy-12x = 0 \implies 6x(y - 2) = 0 \implies x = 0, y = 2$$

We now use these in the second:

$$3y^2+3x^2-12y = 0$$

At $x = 0$, we have:

$$3y(y-4) = 0 \implies y = 0, y = 4$$

At $y = 2$, we have:

$$12+3x^2-24 = 0 \implies x^2 = 4 \implies x = \pm~ 2$$

Putting this all together, we have:

$$(x, y) = (0, 0), (0, 4), (-2, 2), (2,2)$$

Thus, we have a total of four critical points.

Note: sometimes things can get squirrely and it helps if you can draw an contour plot for each equation and see the number of intersection points. For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finding the critical points of one function, is equivalent to finding the zeroes of another function (its derivative).

There is no general rule for how many zeroes a function can have. $\sin x$ has infinitely many zeroes, while $\sin x+2$ has none.

But for polynomials, there can't be more zeroes than the order of the polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

You first invoke the theorem that tells you, in this case, every critical point is a solution to the system of equations $f_x = 0$ and $f_y = 0$.

Thus, if you find the *complete solution* to this system of equations, you have all of the critical points.

This is just a matter of high school algebra; the manipulations you've learned for solving problems do not "lose" any of the solutions. So, as long as you don't make *mistakes* like dividing by $x$ when you don't actually know that $x$ is nonzero, you will find all of the critical points.

However, the manipulations you've learned can *create* new, "spurious" solutions to the simplified problems that aren't solutions to the original problem. This is why you're supposed to *check* all of the solutions you find to be sure they really are solutions.